# How can i stack up tiles in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to learn iOS programming and I decided to make a game like Connect 4, or some may know it as Four in a row.

I've done the grid and dropping the tiles. However, I haven't been able to stack the tiles on top of each other. I havent tried that much because I have no idea on how i could do something like that as i have never tried making a game like this, I have also searched online but I dont know if it's my choice of wording that it never shows anything or if there isnt anything like it. 
I have 7 column on the top, with a hairline where you touch in order to drop the tile to the grid. Right now the tiles just stack on each other.

Comment: Have you considered using Apple's new Sprite Kit?

Comment: Well i already got it started on a single view application. So if it's possible to do it from there.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Maybe post a screenshot, and some code, showing what you have already. You might get a better response.

Comment: could use collision behaviour but there may be a performance issue. Best bet is to use SpriteKit

Comment: @joefryer I dont think i can add photos as I dont have the reputation for that. and also there is no code to show as i dont have anything for the question im looking for an answer.

Comment: @CW0007007 are there any links where i could see a tutorial that you would suggest?

Comment: @user2332292 yeah, look here http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: You can use Sprite kit to do this. You could set up a grid of physics objects and drop in the pieces when the user taps on the top of the grid. You will have to do some reading up on sprite kit in order to start any programming with it. Here is a good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners .

Comment: @MZimmerman6: we posted the same tutorial at almost the same time... i<3 RW tutorials

Comment: So isnt there any way of doing it without using Sprite Kit?

Comment: @user2332292 There are many ways of doing it. I probably would not use Sprite Kit, in favor of using code I am familiar with (quartz and core graphics), but that all depends on personal preference and full need. One thing to note, you can not expect people to just provide you with code without showing some effort on your part.

Comment: @68cherries that is pretty funny. And honestly it was the first result on Google when searching "Sprite Kit tutorial"

Comment: @MZimmerman6 where I don't expect that but since I dont really know a lot on the iOS programming, there isn't much i can do. I have like a million tabs open in chrome, and none of them helps me.

Comment: @user2332292 not to be rude but if not knowing much iOS is the case, someone just giving you the answer is not going to help either, you need the fundamentals so that you can understand what the answerer's code does, and modify it, because it will likely not do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if my response is worth to be an answer but what the heck...

If you are set on not getting into Sprite Kit right now, you could probably use UIButton to make this happen. Divide your screen into a grid of UIButtons. You can set the button images according to empty and played (red or blue). Each button code would have to check for things like if the hole (button) was already played, what color chip to display, is this a winning move, etc... There is of course an easier way to do this instead of copying the same code into each button but I'll let you try to figure that one out for now.

Comment: That is actually a good idea. I dont know what you're talking about the easier way. But this could be a good way of doing it.

Comment: Would it be possible to do it as an array? Have different array for the columns and then everytime i press on one of the grid, add the tile into the array that is allocated for that grid? But im guessing doing that wouldn't be possible since it wont show as the tiles?

Comment: In iOS there are about a gazillion different ways to do the same task (most of the time). You could use arrays to store UIButton states (played by red or blue, empty) but you could also use a class property for each button OR a dictionary OR something else... see what I mean. As for "the easier way", I think you will understand what I meant once you start setting up the action code for each button. You are going to run into a lot of repetition and will start to wonder if there is an easier way. Honestly just start and see how it goes. If you have problems, let me know.

Comment: Alrite thank you, and you're right but its mostly like that in every language.

Comment: Thank you very much, if i could +1 you're answer I would. I found the way to stack them up.

Comment: That's great! As your next project consider doing a calculator using UIButtons. There's more background work involved with a screen to show numbers, keeping current input in memory and so on. Good luck and happy coding!